# Node.js Versions: Recommended vs Current?

Tags: node.js

On the [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/en/), they list two versions, where one is the latest, and the other is the recommended (currently 6.3.0 and 4.4.7).

What is the difference between these two versions, and is the latest version stable enough for production applications?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both are considered stable, as far as reliability goes.

The later builds may use features and APIs that may change.  When they refer to stability in the 6.x branch, they're referring to API stability.  That is, you might write code that works on 6.3, but it might break in 6.4 due to some minor changes.

You can read more here:  https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts_schedule

Comment: Thank you, that link was very helpful.